# How to do parallel execution inside flask view function

Tags: python, flask, parallel-processing, flask-restful

In my `python-flask` web app runs at port `5001`, I have the scenario to create an endpoint where all other endpoint view functions need to be executed parallel and followed by aggregate all the individual responses to return it on same request life cycle.

For example,
`routes` in `flask` app contains, the following `view` functions

```
@app.route(/amazon)
def amazon():
   return "amazon"

@app.route(/flipkart)
def flipkart():
   return "flipkart"

@app.route(/snapdeal)
def sd():
   return "snapdeal"
```

**Note:** In the above three endpoints, significant amount `network io` involved

I am creating another endpoint, where all other endpoint implementations has to be called even here collectively.

```
### This is my endpoint
@app.route(/all)
def do_all():
   # execute all amazon, flipkart, snapdeal implementations
```

I am suggesting two approaches for this above scenario.

#### Approach-1 (Multiprocessing approach):

Writing the worker task as separate function, calling each callers via [python-multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) module and collects the response

```
def do_all():
   def worker(name):
      # doing network io task for the given source name
      pass

   for name in ['amazon', 'flipkart', 'snapdeal']:
      p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=(name,))
      jobs.append(p)
      p.start()

   # Terminating all the process explicitly, Since freezing after execution complete
   for j in jobs:
       j.terminate()

   return 200
```

Here I am invoking each child process, to call the worker, finally all child process gets terminated explicitly, since it is also `wsgi threads` i presume.

#### Approach-2(grequests):

Calling each endpoint explicitly using [python-grequests](https://github.com/kennethreitz/grequests). So, each endpoint which resides in the same app will be called parallel, and collects the response

```
def do_all():
   grequests.post("http://localhost:5001/amazon", data={})
   grequests.post("http://localhost:5001/flipkart", data={})
   grequests.post("http://localhost:5001/snapdeal", data={})
```

This will get executed via each `wsgi threads` will be spawned for each request, Here I have no idea about multiple process spawned and not terminating after execution ?

Both could be similar one, but Which one would be seamless to implement, Please assist me if there is any **alternative way** to solve this scenario? Why?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could simplify it, using another approach:

1. Return immediate response to the User

   `def do_all(): 
       return 'amazon, ... being processed'`
2. Invoke all relevant methods in the background.
3. Let the invoked background methods send [signals](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/signals/)

   `from blinker import Namespace
    background = Namespace()
    amazon_finished = background.signal('amazon-finished')
    def amazon_bg():
        amazon_finished.send(**interesting)`
4. Subscribe to the signals from the background workers.

   `def do_all():
        amazon_finished.connect(amazon_logic)`
5. Display the return values of the background workers to the user. This would be a new request (maybe in the same route).

   `def amazon_logic(sender, **extra):
        sender`

Advantages would be that the User has on each request immediate response to the status of the background workers, error handling would be much easier.

I have not tested it, so you should look up the blinker API for yourself.